# Scroll View not scrolling with relative layout

Tags: android, scrollview

I am busy with an android application and i cant seem to get the scrollView working with my relative layout. I am relatively new to android and this is the first time i am using scroll view.
Here is my xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2000dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fPrice"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_black_24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fName"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric ID"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fid"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric Name"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fRange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fName"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric Range"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fSupplier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fRange"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fRange"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric Supplier"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fWidth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fSupplier"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fSupplier"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric Width"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fWidth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fWidth"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric Style"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fPattern"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric Pattern repeat"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fPattern"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fPattern"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Fabric Unit Price"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fPrice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fPrice"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Add Rail"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab" />



    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView >
```

In the above code, I have a scroll view with a child Relative layout. Could someone please help me solve this problem

Comment: Your height is 2000dp. It's possible that the entirety of the view is less than that amount, so it won't scroll. Try setting this to `match_parent`, or at least something smaller than the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

**The Direct Child Layout to ScrollView height must not be match parent.**
If the child's height is more than scrollview height than only Scroll will work.

In your case you have used *RelativeLayout as Child layout to ScrollView and put its height as match parent.*

I suggest to use **LinearLayout** instead (Recommendation) and **set View height as wrapcontent.**

Along with that in your case set ScrollView height MatchParent.

That will resolve your problem.